# Why did I just get accosted by a unicorn?

Tags: discussion

After resuming my computer from suspend, and clicking on the scifi.stackexchange tab, a unicorn popped up on my screen welcoming me back?  There was no close button on the unicorn, just a couple of options to click on, one which was "don't bother me anymore".

Holy **** the unicorn just popped up again, asking me if I was asking a question about her.

I think this means I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 2):

SPOILERS!

> It's an April Fools joke, you dimbo.

All hail the return of Clippy.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find more details on the main Meta:

[How can I get the 2012 April Fool's joke to appear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127701/how-can-i-get-the-april-fools-joke-to-appear)

It seems that you (or I, for that matter) haven't found all of these, by a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

That's nothing, Adblock just replaced my unicorn with a cat.